# How to write the wc's stdout into a file?

Tags: bash, stdout, xargs

The below command will show how many characters contains in every file in current directory.

```
find  -name '*.*' |xargs  wc -c
```

I want to write the standout into a file.

```
find  -name '*.*' |xargs  wc -c  > /tmp/record.txt
```

It encounter an issue:

```
wc: .: Is a directory
```

How to write all the standard output  into a file?

Comment: `in current directory` - no, find works recursively, so it includes all directories below too. And it outputs also directories, which is the reason you see. `.: Is a directory`. Because `.` is a directory.

Comment: You can check the original markdown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61059046/2).

Comment: Writing the output isn't the problem; `xargs` calling `wc` on a non-regular file is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `-name '*.*'`? That will not find every file and will find directories. You need to use `-type f`, and better than piping the result to `xargs` is using `-exec`:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec wc -c {} + > /tmp/record.txt
```

`-maxdepth 1` guarantees that the search won't dive in subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe meant `find |xargs wc -c`?

`find -name '.'` just returns `.`

Answer (score 0):

Filter only files, if you want only files.

```
find -type f
```